# Buy X Get Another X Free Magento

Tags: php, magento, conditional-statements, rules

Trying to find out how I can create a rule in Magento where you buy x product and you get another x free automatically but has to work more than once so if you buy 2 X you get 2X More free.

Also it has to work with to different SKU's

Sample Scenario will be in my cart i have 1X SKU is 001 and 1x 002 on my rules 001 and 002 are included on the promo so 002 will be free. But if add 4 items from product X with sku 004 2 of them are free as well.

I want the cart to be able to calculate for each 1 you add to cart you get 1 free from the group of sku's but they can be mixed i don't want the to be 2 of same kind.

So Buy X Get 1 Free from a group of sku's and cart must be able to know that if i have 3 more are free but the problem is if i only have 3 items it show as a total of 0.00 making the cart free.

Comment: [Magneto.SE](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart-price-rules) has a lot of questions like this. You might try looking there.